# How to edit Kibana config file in Docker?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, elasticsearch, kibana

I am running Kibana from a docker container on Windows. Kibana is asking me put something in the file config/kibana.yml. I found the file in Docker desktop Terminal, but how do I edit it? What editor can I use in Docker desktop? Where do I find this file in Windows Explorer to use notepad? Searching on kibana.yml under Linux produced about a dozen of references to some obscure folders.

Comment: If you can share the command you use for run the kibana, I can help you to build a new one with kibana.yml

Comment: Why are not you using environment variables?

Comment: Kibana is telling me this:
In your config/kibana.yml file, set enterpriseSearch.host to the URL of your Workplace Search instance. For example:
enterpriseSearch.host: 'http://localhost:3002'

How can I do that with environment variables?

Comment: Why not to create a separate kibana.yml file locally and copy it to KBN_PATH_CONF directory in your Dockerfile ? If you update the configuration inside docker container, to make sure changes are taking into effect, you need to restart the container and your changes essentially will be lost.

Comment: Thanks, Ayush, this is useful.